# How to organize a multi-part meeting in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

Alice and Bob from [Initech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Space) are coming over for a coulpe of meetings. They need to talk to Carol, Dave (me), Eve, and Frank separately and they have asked me to setup a meeting.

I don't have access to the agendas of my co-workers, not with "Create Items" permission. Also, I need to book a room for the entire time they're here.

I tried to do this by

1. Booking a room, just for myself, for the entire time it's needed, but setting the meeting to "Show As: Free" as I won't need it the entire time myself.
2. Booking separate meetings for each cow-orker, with me as the organizer, but again with "Show As: Free" and explaining that I won't be present, that I'm just organizing.
3. Sending a summary / itinerary to Alice and Bob (I'm not sending the actual invites out to them).

I thought this would work, but ["I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey_(film)) Specifically, I didn't add the room to the separate meetings since I thought I'd already booked it. Unfortunately, since I booked it with "Show As: Free", it didn't show up as occupied and someone else has booked a meeting in it.

So how should I have handled this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is given in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/986020/278826):

> Just book the room as usual and **then** go to your calendar and switch your status to "Free" for this meeting.

This allows me to book the room without setting myself as "Busy" for the entire time of the visit.

---

It would be preferable to be able to book the room for the entire visit as one block and then plan different meetings in it, but this'll do.