# How to book a room but not set my calendar as busy

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I need to book a room for a few days. At the same time I want my calendar for these days to remain 'free' (so that others can book a meeting with me).

If I force 'free' as the status for that booking/meeting, the room is not booked (or at least appear as 'not busy' and thus can be booked over (I guess).

Is there a way to book a room so that it is busy, but my availability is 'free'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this is easy. Just book the room as usual and **then** go to your calendar and switch your status to "Free" for this meeting.

Comment: Thanks - I mentioned this solution in my question. The room then becomes 'free' as well and is visible as free (which is a problem if someone wants to book it) and for me (as the room is "bookable", i.e. someone's meeting in that room will not be rejected because the room is 'busy' (if this is the mechanism used by Exchange to decide whether a room is available or not,))

Comment: This is weird. It works flawless for me and always worked. Are you sure you've booked the room normally (as Busy), confirmed it is busy (as well as yourself) and *then* go to your calendar in Outlook and mark yourself as Free?

Comment: Interesting - I did the test again and this time it worked as designed (the room is booked and I am 'free'). Thanks for pushing me to try again :)